# I use Jquery addClass() to change background, but it's not work in IE6

Tags: jquery, hover, internet-explorer-6

I use Jquery addClass() method to change DIV's background when the mouse is over it,but why it doesn't work in IE6,however,font color is changed. URL: http://www.wfuns.com/soiseek

CSS:

```css
#container #index_sidebar .mycats .item{
   width:200px;
   height:auto;
   overflow:hidden;
   padding:8px 10px 12px 10px;
   *padding:8 0 12px;/*IE7*/
   position:relative;
   z-index:200;
   background:#59a818 url(../img/icons/menu_icon.png) no-repeat 179px -27px;
   border-bottom:1px solid #78c03d;
}
/*Hover*/
#container #index_sidebar .mycats .hover_bg{
   background:#fff;
}
#container #index_sidebar .mycats .hover_bg a{
   color:#59a818;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```js
 $('#index_sidebar .mycats .item').bind({
       mouseover: function() {
        $(this).addClass("hover_bg");
      },
      mouseout: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover_bg"); 
      }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="index_sidebar">
      <div class="mycats">
        <div class="item"><a href="#" class="parent">Category</a>
          <p class="sub_cats"><a href="#">NXP</a> <a href="#">ABB</a> <a href="#">CTS</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub_menu">
          <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: General rule of thumb; As carefully as you craft your styles, they still will not work in IE6. Why are you still supporting it?

Comment: you are missing the `#container` in your demo, than a `</div>` and... After I add all that it works in IE. (IE6 I mean)

Comment: Don't forget to test on Firefox 1.0 too, that was released years after IE 6 ;)  Some things are best left in a corner to die quietly.

Comment: It should work once you correct your HTML. Add another `</div>` at the end.

Comment: This doesn't work in Netscape Navigator 1.22

Comment: @goldilocks and TravisJ - you'll note that the site is in Chinese, and that China has a significantly higher usage of IE6 than other countries. Given that, he is probably justified in wanting to support it. I agree that IE6 does need to die, though.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need any jQuery or Javascript code for this at all.

You just need to know about the CSS `:hover` feature, which does exactly what you're trying to do here without needing all that code.

You probably added the code to work around the fact that `:hover` doesn't work properly in IE6, but you don't need this code; just use one of the IE6-hover hacks, such as [Whatever:hover](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html).

So all you need is this CSS:

```
#container #index_sidebar .mycats .item:hover {
    background:#fff;
}
#container #index_sidebar .mycats .item:hover a {
    color:#59a818;
}
```

...plus the `behavior` style as described on the Whatever:Hover site, and it will work beautifully in all browsers, without any Javascript code.

(okay, yes, Whatever:hover is written in Javascript, so technically there is some JS code, but only in IE6, it's out of the way of the rest of your code, and it's never even seen by any other browser)

Comment: The salient point here is that IE6 doesn't support `:hover` on all elements (only `<a>` IIRC)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I use Whatever:hover but it's still no background-color in IE6.

Comment: @steveax - the other salient point is that `Whatever:hover` solves that issue in IE6.

Comment: @BadJohnny - can you show us your edited CSS containing the Whatever:hover code, and also confirm that the Whatever:hover script file is in your site.

Comment: But there's no improve. I think is it possible CSS doesn't compatible IE6?

Comment: I add it at body{behavior:url("js/csshover3.htc");} and CSS code is the same to yours.

Comment: I test it in ietester, alert that Access is denied to csshover3.htc file

Comment: @BadJohnny - not sure why it would do that. Maybe the URL needs to be `url("/js/csshover3.htc")` with a leading slash?

Comment: There's no change after modify HTC file path. I think the problem is not on this. At first I used Jquery addClass() method to instead of :hover, the font color is changed but no background color,then I use $(this).css("background":"#fff"), that's OK,however,another problem occurs,background is flicker when the mouse is hover.